# Defined as integers but the compiler think one of them is double?

Tags: c++, g++, double

Here is a code I have written, although there is no double variable in it, g++ throws this warning: "invalid operands of types ‘double’ and ‘int’ to binary ‘operator%’
 c = pow(m,e)%n;
" How is that?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/dynamic_bitset.hpp>
#include <math.h>


using namespace std;

int main()
{
boost::dynamic_bitset <> seq(5);
int key = 0;
int p = 0, q = 0;
int n = 0;
int f = 0;
int d = 0;
int e = 0;
int c = 0;
int m = 0;
int t = 0;
cout << "Enter a sequence of bits: ";
cin >> seq;
for (unsigned int i = 0; i <  seq.size(); i++)
{
 if ( seq[i]==1)
  {
   d = d + pow(2,i);
   cout << d << "\n";
  }
}
//cout << key << "\n";
cout << "Enter p: ";
cin >> p;
cout << "Enter q: ";
cin >> q;
cout << "Enter m: ";
cin >> m;
n = p*q;
f = (p-1)*(q-1);
for ( int k = 0; t < 1; k++)
 {
  if ((1+k*f)%d==0)
   {
    t = 2;
    e = (1+k*f)/d;
   }
 }
cout << "E is: " << e << "\n";
c = pow(m,e)%n;
cout << "C is: " << c << "\n";
cin.get();
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Have you seen how `std::pow` is implemented (i.e., what it returns)? http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cmath/pow/

Comment: Thank you, I have only seen it now.

Comment: You don't have to, since it's answered. ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Function pow is declared as

```
double pow (double base, double exponent)
```

that is a double.

Comment: Thank you! It is interesting to know that a function may take integer variables and return a double. I see that those variable are coveted to double if they were not.